# correct one column in a csv file and, add it again as a new column

Tags: pandas, csv

I have an existing CSV file with 8 columns in it containing tweets, links, Ids, etc. I have cleaned one column including tweets using pandas, and I am going to add cleaned column as a new column to the existing CSV file using pandas or CSV packages. in other words, in the 4th column, I have a tweet, and I am going to have the cleaned tweet at the 9 column and the same row.  would you please help me?

```
 import pandas as pd
    #my existing file
    data=pd.read_csv("myfile" , sep= '{,' ,  header=None )
    data_list = data.get_values().tolist()
    #cleaned row
    for row in data_list:
        second_data = strip_all_entities(strip_links(row[4]))
        print (second_data)
    #adding new column
    with open("F:/final_tweet.csv", 'w') as newfile:
    newfileWriter = csv.writer(newfile)
    for item in second_data:
        newfileWriter.writerow([item])
```

I have a CSV file including 8 columns, 10476 rows, while I am going to add a new column in which the 4th column was cleaned. finally, I am going to have a CSV file including 9 column and 10476 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all here you don't save your new data, you just iterate rows of your dataframe and overwrite your corrected data at every iteration.

```
for row in data_list:
    second_data = strip_all_entities(strip_links(row[4]))
    print (second_data)
```

So you can organize a list and save your new data to it:

```
newdata = []
for row in data_list:
    second_data = strip_all_entities(strip_links(row[4]))
    newdata.append(second_data)
    print (second_data)
```

Then it is better to add the column to `data` dataframe .

```
data["newcolumn"] = newdata
```

And after then you can save your dataframe to csv.